# complex startkey/endkey query concerning PouchDB not returning expected result

Tags: javascript, couchdb, pouchdb

I have created an index called `session_indexes/by_lastModifiedDate_status` in pouchdb to emit both a timestamp as well as a string, which indicates the status.

Here are the array keys that get emitted when the map function is run with 6 documents in the database:

```
[1404446400000, 'SUSPENDED']
[1409630400000, 'OPEN']
[1413777600000, 'OPEN']
[1423976400000, 'CLOSED']
[1425704400000, 'OPEN']
[1430193600000, 'OPEN']
```

Now, I want to query this index using `startkey` and `endkey`. I do so by providing the following:

```
startkey: [1422766800000, 'CLOSED']
endkey: [1427688000000, 'CLOSED']
```

This means I want to find all of the documents that have a date between these two timestamps and have a `CLOSED` status.

However, PouchDB seems to return only the results that match the dates - so it's returning 2 results (the other one being `[1425704400000, 'OPEN']`).

The map function I am using is as follows. I know it looks strange - but this is actually being generated by code. It was not written by a human. But it still emits the correct keys just fine:

```
function(document) {
  if(document._id.startsWith('session')) {
    var keys = [];

    if(document.lastModifiedDate) {
      keys.push(document.lastModifiedDate);
    }

    if(document.status) {
      keys.push(document.status.text.toUpperCase());
    }

    emit(keys, null);
  }
}
```

The query itself is as follows:

```
return Database.instance().query('session_indexes/by_lastModifiedDate_status', {
    startkey: [1422766800000, 'CLOSED'],
    endkey: [1427688000000, 'CLOSED'],
    include_docs: true
}).then(function(result) {
    return _(result.rows).map(function(row) {
        return Session.fromDocument(row.doc, new Session());
    });
});
```

**EDIT**: It would appear that if I reverse the order and put the status first, the query works as expected. Can I ask why? And how can I fix that?

I'd appreciate any help you can provide me. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works that way because of CouchDB collation ordering. E.g. for numbers+letters, you'd have:

`[1, A]
[1, B]
[2, A]
[2, B]`

etc.

Comment: Hi Nolan :) Put another way - How to do I actually create the query I want to create? I think I understand how startkey/endkey REALLY work now. I didn't before, but now I understand that the entire key array is actually flat and one-dimensional. So If the startkey was `[1,A]` and the endkey was `[2,A]`, it's going to select `[1,B]` too, which is contrary to SQL filtering in the WHERE clause. I get that it's NOT a where clause now :) But I am still lost as to how to create the query I want to make unless I don't make a secondary index. Do I filter using JavaScript?

Comment: You can reverse the order and then do two separate queries. :)